# Can a WCF ServiceRoute Route Prefix contain a path value?

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, routes

Currently I use this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("API", new WebServiceHostFactory(),typeof(MySite.Web.MyServiceV1)));
```

To make this url point to the MyServiceV1.SVC 
MySite.com/API

---

I want to use a Prefix which contains a / in it but it doesn't seem to work.

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("API/V2", new WebServiceHostFactory(),typeof(MySite.Web.MyServiceV2)));
```

Is there a better way to represent this instead of having to do "APIV2" ?
I am using .Net 4.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I totally forgot that the order you register routes mattered. This works:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("API/V2/", new WebServiceHostFactory(),typeof(MySite.Web.MyServiceV2)))

RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("API/", new WebServiceHostFactory(),typeof(MySite.Web.MyServiceV1)));
```