# Orchard/MVC WCF Service Url with Area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, rest, orchardcms

Bertrand created a blog [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/04/20/orchard-1-1-what-s-in-it-for-developers.aspx) to specify how to use IoC in WCF Modules for Orchard.

In 1.1, you can create a SVC file using the new Orchard host factory:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
    Service="MyModule.IMyService, MyAssembly"
    Factory="Orchard.Wcf.OrchardServiceHostFactory, Orchard.Framework" %>
Then register your service normally as an IDependency but with service and operation contract attributes:

using System.ServiceModel;

namespace MyModule {
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService : IDependency {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetUserEmail(string username);
    }
}
```

My question is that all of Orchard's modules are really area's. So how can you build a route that hits the svc file created in the area/module?

Should you use the full physical path to get to the svc file (tried that and it caused a web.config issue since it was bridging a site and area).

```
http://localhost/modules/WebServices/MyService.svc
```

Or do you create a ServiceRoute with WebServiceHostFactory/OrchardServiceHostFactory?

```
new ServiceRoute("WebServices/MyService", new OrchardServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MyService))
```

Whatever I try I get a 404 when trying to hit the resource. I was able to get this working using a wcf Application project and setting WCF as a stand alone application, my issues started when trying to bring it into Orchard/MVC.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the help Piotr,

This is the steps I took to implement the service.

Routes.cs

```
new RouteDescriptor {   Priority = 20,
                        Route = new ServiceRoute(
                                      "Services",
                                      new WebServiceHostFactory(),
                                      typeof(MyService)) }
```

If I use OrchardServiceHostFactory() instead of WebServiceHostFactory() I get the following error.

```
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
```

Orchard Root Web.Config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <!-- 
            Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
            via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
        -->
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

MyService

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService : IDependency
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetTest();
}

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
class MyService : IMyService
{
    public string GetTest()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

I couldn't get the service working by just modifying the module's web.config. I get the following error

```
ASP.NET routing integration feature requires ASP.NET compatibility.
```

**UPDATE 2**

Orchard Root Web.Config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <!-- ... -->
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Routes.cs

```
public IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes() {
    return new[] {
                     new RouteDescriptor {   Priority = 20,
                                             Route = new ServiceRoute(
                                                 "Services",
                                                 new OrchardServiceHostFactory(),
                                                 typeof(IMyService))

                     }
                 };
}
```

This works, the key here is that you must call typeof on the object that is referencing IDependency, WorkContextModule.IsClosingTypeOf cant handle the object that consumes the dependancy, it must take the Interface that it is directly called by.

Comment: Try changing the *RequirementsMode* from *Allowed* to *Required* on your service class. I'll try to investigate what is casuing the problem.

Comment: Same issue. I created a hg repository at https://bitbucket.org/e2software/orchardwcf if you wanted to see the sample module and see the error first hand.

Comment: I guess the problem is because your service implementation is marked as *internal*. Try making it *public* and it should work without the need for that typeof(IMyService) hack. Internal methods are invisible for the underlying DI engine and they are just ignored...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated, Orchard modules are areas in ASP.NET MVC terms, so the URL you provided is incorrect and should be:

```
http://localhost/Your.Orchard.Module/WebServices/MyService.svc
```

Where *localhost* is the virtual directory under which your app runs and */WebServices* is a folder in the root of your module.

You can also create a service route programatically without problem. [This](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Building-a-hello-world-module.ashx?#Adding_the_Route_3) article tells how to add new routes in Orchard. You can just assign a **ServiceRoute** to the **Route** property of a RouteDescriptor instead of a default MVC route (as shown in docs).
[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047485/expose-wcf-services-that-belong-to-an-area-in-mvc-app-at-a-routed-path) about adding ServiceRoute in area-enabled ASP.NET MVC app was asked before, check it out as it may help you out.

Btw - You may also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186858/can-a-wcf-serviceroute-route-prefix-contain-a-path-value) SO question about prefixed service routes.

HTH

Comment: When I go to  http://localhost/Your.Orchard.Module/WebServices/MyService.svc I get the error The IControllerFactory 'Orchard.Mvc.OrchardControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'Data'. and if I use OrchardServiceHostFactory in the route, I get Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. WebServiceHostFactory works fine though.