# How to retrieve Orchard CMS content from another site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, orchardcms

Are there any Orchard web services I could call to retrieve content from my Orchard site so that I could display on another site? Two separate sets of servers.

Answer (score 1):

You can expose Orchard content via web services without any problems. All you have to do is to create a module with WCF service inside (as in ordinary ASP.NET-based web app) and add an appropriate *ServiceRoute* pointing to that service.

You can read more about how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795632/orchard-mvc-wcf-service-url-with-area) and [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/04/20/orchard-1-1-what-s-in-it-for-developers.aspx).

***UPDATE:*** As Bertrand noted, you can also take the easier way and setup a simple REST service using a plain ASP.NET MVC controller.

Comment: Or go REST with a plain controller if you don't want to put up with WCF.