# Orchard CMS WCF Service with ServiceRoute

Tags: web-services, orchardcms

I have configured a Orchard module to expose a service and have enabled it. I cannot work out the URL to use based on the following.

Routes.cs

```
namespace OrchardRestService
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

    using Orchard.Mvc.Routes;
    using Orchard.Wcf;

    public class Routes : IRouteProvider
    {
        #region Implementation of IRouteProvider

        public IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes()
        {
            return new[] {
                new RouteDescriptor {
                   Priority = 20,
                        Route = new ServiceRoute(
                                      "ContentService",
                                      new OrchardServiceHostFactory(),
                                      typeof(IContentService))
                }
            };
        }

        public void GetRoutes(ICollection<RouteDescriptor> routes)
        {
            foreach (var routeDescriptor in GetRoutes())
                routes.Add(routeDescriptor);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

IContentService.cs:

```
namespace OrchardRestService
{
    using System.ServiceModel;

    using Orchard;

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IContentService : IDependency
    {
        [OperationContract]
        ContentResult GetContent(string contentPath);
    }
}
```

ContentService.cs:

```
namespace OrchardRestService
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class ContentService : IContentService
    {
        public ContentResult GetContent(string contentPath)
        {
            var contentResult = new ContentResult
                { ContentValues = new Dictionary<string, string>(), Found = true, Path = contentPath };
            return contentResult;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to follow what Bertrand Le Roy has written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795632/orchard-mvc-wcf-service-url-with-area) and [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/04/20/orchard-1-1-what-s-in-it-for-developers.aspx) but seem to be missing something.

My code is .Net 4 by the way so no need for an SVC file.

Answer (score 1):

Closing as I'd be jumping through hoops to use N2 in this way rather than what it is designed for.